# ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'shafquetnaghmi'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

models.py

After adding this model,when i run python manage.py migrate this  problem arises,there i added default='shafquetnaghmi' in sender but i removed it ,still it is not working.

```
class instantmessage(models.Model):
    sender=models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='sender', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    receiver=models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='receiver')
    message=models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.message}'
```

Operations to perform:

```
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, social_django, socialapp
Running migrations:
  Applying socialapp.0006_remove_instantmessage_sender_instantmessage_sender...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1822, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'shafquetnaghmi'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\socialnetwork\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\socialnetwork\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute    
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv  
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute        
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 90, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 253, in hanp_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 2461, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)  File "C:\Users\SHAFQUET NAGHMI\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 1824, in get_prep_value
    raise e.__class__(ValueError: Field 'id' expected a number but got 'shafquetnaghmi'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have deleted it in code, but in migrations it is still applied.

Suggested fix:
You have to delete all migrations - `socialapp.0006_remove_instantmessage_sender_instantmessage_sender` and later ones (0007_*.py and on, if you have them). Then delete database and run `makemigrations` and `migrate` again.

You can also edit `socialapp.0006_remove_instantmessage_sender_instantmessage_sender` and delete `default='shafquetnaghmi'` from that model there. It also needs database drop probably.